# What is the different between the markup

Tags: html, css

I am confuse what is the different between this markup.

```
<div class="pic">   
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/333/333" alt="">
</div>
```

css

```
.pic {
width: 600px;
background: red;
}
```

now i can see my background but when i did another markup like bellow.. i can't figure out..

another markup:

```
<img class="pic" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/333/333" alt="">
```

same style..

Comment: Your problem is that you can't see the color red?

Comment: You already seen my first markup when i used css for the first markup i got 600px width and then i got image.. but wen i did my 2nd markup i can't got my width. so is it for nested class of div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First case :**

```css
.pic {
width: 600px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic">   
<img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/333/333" alt="">
</div>
```

Here img element is inside the div tag and you have specified some css for div i.e `.pic` which contains width of `600px` which is assigned to div tag.

And img tag loads inside that div tag which takes some size that it has.
This image size is lesses than 600px so you can see background color.If it would be larger than 600px it come out of that div also.

**Second case:**

```css
.pic {
width: 600px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<img class="pic" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/333/333" alt="">
```

Here you directly assigned that css to img tag. so img tag takes width of 600px. so we can't see any background color here.

Comment: @BapyMridha You are Welcome. Glad to help you. Keep Coding!